# ubuntu 23.10. Error updating the kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, gcc

### Prop. of my Ubuntu

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 23.10"

```
uname -r

5.15.0-72-generic
```

### Error updating the kernel to version 6.5

***dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/make.log***

```
DKMS make.log for anbox-ashmem-1 for kernel 6.5.0-060500-generic (x86_64)
Wed Feb 28 12:16:29 AM CST 2024
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-060500-generic/build V=0 M=$PWD
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-060500-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-6ubuntu1) 13.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/deps.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/ashmem.o
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/ashmem.c: In function ‘ashmem_mmap’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/ashmem.c:393:23: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
  393 |         vma->vm_flags &= ~calc_vm_may_flags(~asma->prot_mask);
      |                       ^~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/ashmem.c: In function ‘ashmem_init’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/ashmem.c:877:9: error: too few arguments to function ‘register_shrinker’
  877 |         register_shrinker(&ashmem_shrinker);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/list_lru.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:13,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/ashmem.c:25:
./include/linux/shrinker.h:102:27: note: declared here
  102 | extern int __printf(2, 3) register_shrinker(struct shrinker *shrinker,
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build/ashmem.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-060500-generic/Makefile:2038: /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-060500-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:12: all] Error 2
```

***dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/make.log***

```
DKMS make.log for anbox-binder-1 for kernel 6.5.0-060500-generic (x86_64)
Wed Feb 28 12:16:31 AM CST 2024
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-060500-generic/build V=0 M=$PWD
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-060500-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-6ubuntu1) 13.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/deps.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.o
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘task_get_unused_fd_flags’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:444:16: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__alloc_fd’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  444 |         return __alloc_fd(files, 0, rlim_cur, flags);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘task_fd_install’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:454:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__fd_install’; did you mean ‘fd_install’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  454 |                 __fd_install(proc->files, fd, file);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 fd_install
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘task_close_fd’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:467:18: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__close_fd’; did you mean ‘close_fd’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  467 |         retval = __close_fd(proc->files, fd);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                  close_fd
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘binder_update_page_range’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:633:33: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
  633 |                 down_write(&mm->mmap_sem);
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~
      |                                 mmap_base
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:663:23: error: implicit declaration of function ‘map_kernel_range_noflush’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  663 |                 ret = map_kernel_range_noflush((unsigned long)page_addr,
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:683:31: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
  683 |                 up_write(&mm->mmap_sem);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~
      |                               mmap_base
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:694:25: error: implicit declaration of function ‘zap_page_range’; did you mean ‘copy_page_range’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  694 |                         zap_page_range(vma, (uintptr_t)page_addr +
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         copy_page_range
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:701:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘unmap_kernel_range’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  701 |                 unmap_kernel_range((unsigned long)page_addr, PAGE_SIZE);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:710:31: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘mmap_sem’; did you mean ‘mmap_base’?
  710 |                 up_write(&mm->mmap_sem);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~
      |                               mmap_base
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘binder_translate_binder’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:1626:49: error: passing argument 1 of ‘security_binder_transfer_binder’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1626 |         if (security_binder_transfer_binder(proc->tsk, target_proc->tsk))
      |                                             ~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 struct task_struct *
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:48:
./include/linux/security.h:268:56: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  268 | int security_binder_transfer_binder(const struct cred *from,
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:1626:67: error: passing argument 2 of ‘security_binder_transfer_binder’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1626 |         if (security_binder_transfer_binder(proc->tsk, target_proc->tsk))
      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                                   |
      |                                                                   struct task_struct *
./include/linux/security.h:269:56: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  269 |                                     const struct cred *to);
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘binder_translate_handle’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:1668:49: error: passing argument 1 of ‘security_binder_transfer_binder’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1668 |         if (security_binder_transfer_binder(proc->tsk, target_proc->tsk))
      |                                             ~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 struct task_struct *
./include/linux/security.h:268:56: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  268 | int security_binder_transfer_binder(const struct cred *from,
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:1668:67: error: passing argument 2 of ‘security_binder_transfer_binder’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1668 |         if (security_binder_transfer_binder(proc->tsk, target_proc->tsk))
      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                                   |
      |                                                                   struct task_struct *
./include/linux/security.h:269:56: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  269 |                                     const struct cred *to);
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘binder_translate_fd’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:1740:49: error: passing argument 1 of ‘security_binder_transfer_file’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1740 |         ret = security_binder_transfer_file(proc->tsk, target_proc->tsk, file);
      |                                             ~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 struct task_struct *
./include/linux/security.h:270:54: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  270 | int security_binder_transfer_file(const struct cred *from,
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:1740:67: error: passing argument 2 of ‘security_binder_transfer_file’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1740 |         ret = security_binder_transfer_file(proc->tsk, target_proc->tsk, file);
      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                                   |
      |                                                                   struct task_struct *
./include/linux/security.h:271:54: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  271 |                                   const struct cred *to, struct file *file);
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘binder_transaction’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:1967:53: error: passing argument 1 of ‘security_binder_transaction’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1967 |                 if (security_binder_transaction(proc->tsk,
      |                                                 ~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                     |
      |                                                     struct task_struct *
./include/linux/security.h:266:52: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  266 | int security_binder_transaction(const struct cred *from,
      |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:1968:60: error: passing argument 2 of ‘security_binder_transaction’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1968 |                                                 target_proc->tsk) < 0) {
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                            |
      |                                                            struct task_struct *
./include/linux/security.h:267:52: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  267 |                                 const struct cred *to);
      |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘binder_ioctl_set_ctx_mgr’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:3262:51: error: passing argument 1 of ‘security_binder_set_context_mgr’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 3262 |         ret = security_binder_set_context_mgr(proc->tsk);
      |                                               ~~~~^~~~~
      |                                                   |
      |                                                   struct task_struct *
./include/linux/security.h:265:56: note: expected ‘const struct cred *’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
  265 | int security_binder_set_context_mgr(const struct cred *mgr);
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘binder_mmap’:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:3436:23: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
 3436 |         vma->vm_flags = (vma->vm_flags | VM_DONTCOPY) & ~VM_MAYWRITE;
      |                       ^
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:3486:23: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_files_struct’; did you mean ‘put_files_struct’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 3486 |         proc->files = get_files_struct(current);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                       put_files_struct
In file included from ./include/linux/linkage.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/printk.h:8,
                 from ./include/asm-generic/bug.h:22,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/bug.h:87,
                 from ./include/linux/bug.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/mmdebug.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:6,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cacheflush.h:5,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:20:
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c: In function ‘binder_init’:
./include/linux/export.h:29:22: error: passing argument 1 of ‘class_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   29 | #define THIS_MODULE (&__this_module)
      |                     ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                      |
      |                      struct module *
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:4371:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘THIS_MODULE’
 4371 |         binder_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "binder");
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/device.h:31,
                 from ./include/linux/cdev.h:8,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:21:
./include/linux/device/class.h:230:54: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct module *’
  230 | struct class * __must_check class_create(const char *name);
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.c:4371:24: error: too many arguments to function ‘class_create’
 4371 |         binder_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "binder");
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/device/class.h:230:29: note: declared here
  230 | struct class * __must_check class_create(const char *name);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/binder.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-060500-generic/Makefile:2038: /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-060500-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 2
```

Comment: seems to be a common problem with anbox https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules/issues/109 https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules/issues/75#issuecomment-794079944

Comment: Ubuntu Kernel is already at 6.5 on a native Ubuntu machine. Have that here